# Python loop through array deeply. Tree

Tags: python, loops

Need advice concerning looping.

I have an array of elements.

I need to loop through array and check every element for a regular expression. If the element matches the regex, I call a function, which returns new array of elements. I should then loop through this array of new elements doing the same procedure before I continue with iteration. This is like depth-first search in a tree.

It seems that I need use "while" loop, but I can't figure out the logic.

For example:

```
def get_elements(element):
   #some code
   return elements

def loop_through_elements(elements):
    for element in elements:
       if re.search("myRegExp", element):
          elements = get_elements(element);
       else:
          return element
```

Comment: So if `re.search` is successful you no longer loop through the remaining old elements? Because in your `if` block you're replacing elements with whatever is returned by `get_elements`. Is this correct?

Comment: So what do you want that function to return?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Den has a problem in his original code. get_element is not supposed to overwrite the main elements array, it's supposed to produce a new list of elements that should be iterated through *before* continuing with the original iteration.

Comment: @jfbeltran yes, you're right.

Comment: @Goyo The function get_elements must return the new array of elements depends on the element from "if" statement at loop_through_elements. And iterate through the new array until there are elements. Also, each element of the new array could be new array. 
Incoming data for the script would look like the tree of directories and "files". So I need to check via regular expression for matching "directory". And if element match "directory" reg.exp - do get "subfolders" and loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that each element is either a string or an interable type (such as a list), we can solve this using recursion:

```
def examine_element(element):
    """ Examine a single element
    """
    if re.search("myREgExp", element):
        pass # TODO

def examine_each_element(elements):
    """ Examine all elements recursively
    """
    for element in elements:
        if isinstance(str, element):
            # This element is a single element
            examine_element(element)
        else:
            # This element represents multiple elements
            examine_each_element(elements)
```

Note that there are a couple of limitations to this approach which you should watch out for:

1. This will loop forever if your structure is not a DAG (directed, acyclical graph). Since you mentioned it's a tree, you should be fine.
2. If your tree is excessively large, this will fail because you will run out of stack space. In this case, you should try an iterative approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a recursive function and call "loop_through_elements(elements)" inside it's definition.

```
def loop_through_elements(elements):
    for element in elements:
        if re.search("myRegExp", element):
            loop_through_elements(get_elements(element))
        else:
            return element
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a depth-first iteration through your elements you can think about the logic like this:

```
def loop_through_elements(elements):
    for element in elements:
       if re.search("myRegExp", element):
          child_elements = get_elements(element)
          return loop_through_elements(child_elements)
       else:
          return element
```

There's 3 things that are different from your code:

1. You want to make sure you don't overwrite your "elements"
   variable when you get new elements. Instead I am calling these
   "child_elements".
2. I've added a call to loop_through_elements inside the function loop_through_elements. This is called [recursion](https://thepythonguru.com/python-recursive-functions/)! If this concept is new to you I suggest reading a bit more about it, as this example might not be a super clear place to learn about recursion.
3. I've added another return statement **but** you should think about what this function does now and whether it fits what you want it to do. What happens when you find an element that doesn't match the regex in a "deeper" level of the tree? Are you guaranteed to check the whole tree if everything matches the regex? Should you have some special condition if you finish the for loop without ever going "deeper" in the tree?